# Getting a System.Error when attempting to Sync using batching in Sync Framework

Tags: c#, wcf, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am writing an n-tiered application that uses the Sync Framework v2.1 in combination with a WCF web service. My code is based on this example: [Database-Sync](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-SQL-Server-7e88adab)

Syncing seems to work without a problem. But, when I add the batching functionality I get an error that is proving difficult to debug.

In the client portion of the solution (a WPF app), I have a virtual class that inherits from KnowledgeSyncProvider. It also implements the IDisposable interface. I use this class to call the WCF service I wrote and use the sync functionality there.  When the sync code runs (orchestrator.Synchronize() is called), everything seems to work correctly and the EndSession function override that I have written runs without error. But, after execution leaves that function, a System.Error occurs from within Microsoft.Synchronization.CoreInterop.ISyncSession.Start (as far as I can tell).

The functions I have written to provide the IDisposable functionality are never called so, something is happening after EndSession, but before my application's KnowledgeSyncProvider virtual class can be disposed.

Here is the error information:

_message: "System error."
Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.Synchronization.CoreInterop.ISyncSession.Start(CONFLICT_RESOLUTION_POLICY resolutionPolicy, _SYNC_SESSION_STATISTICS& pSyncSessionStatistics)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWaySyncHelper(SyncIdFormatGroup sourceIdFormats, SyncIdFormatGroup destinationIdFormats, KnowledgeSyncProviderConfiguration destinationConfiguration, SyncCallbacks DestinationCallbacks, ISyncProvider sourceProxy, ISyncProvider destinationProxy, ChangeDataAdapter callbackChangeDataAdapter, SyncDataConverter conflictDataConverter, Int32& changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWayKnowledgeSync(SyncDataConverter sourceConverter, SyncDataConverter destinationConverter, SyncProvider sourceProvider, SyncProvider destinationProvider, Int32& changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.Synchronize()
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncOrchestrator.Synchronize()
   at MyApplication.Library.SynchronizationHelper.SynchronizeProviders() in C:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyApplication\MyApplication\Library\SynchronizationHelper.cs:line 43
   at MyApplication.ViewModels.MainViewModel.SynchronizeDatabases() in C:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyApplication\MyApplication\ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs:line 46

I have enabled trace info but, that doesn't seem to provide any helpful information in this case.

Can anyone make a suggestion as to how I might be able to figure out what is causing this error?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Here is the code that handles syncing:

```
public void SynchronizeProviders()
```

{
        CeDatabase localDb = new CeDatabase();
        localDb.Location = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\Data\SYNCTESTING5.sdf";
        RelationalSyncProvider localProvider = ConfigureCeSyncProvider(localDb.Connection);
        MyAppKnowledgeSyncProvider srcProvider = new MyAppKnowledgeSyncProvider();
        localProvider.MemoryDataCacheSize = 5000;
        localProvider.BatchingDirectory = "c:\batchingdir";
    srcProvider.BatchingDirectory = "c:\batchingdir";

```
SyncOrchestrator orchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
orchestrator.LocalProvider = localProvider;
orchestrator.RemoteProvider = srcProvider;
orchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

CheckIfProviderNeedsSchema(localProvider as SqlCeSyncProvider, srcProvider);
SyncOperationStatistics stats = orchestrator.Synchronize();
```

}

And here is the KnowledgeSyncProviderClass that is used to create srcProvider:

```
   class MyAppKnowledgeSyncProvider : KnowledgeSyncProvider, IDisposable
{
    protected MyAppSqlSync.IMyAppSqlSync proxy;
    protected SyncIdFormatGroup idFormatGroup;
    protected DirectoryInfo localBatchingDirectory;
    protected bool disposed = false;

    private string batchingDirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%TEMP%");

    public string BatchingDirectory
    {
        get { return batchingDirectory; }
        set 
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("value cannot be null or empty");
            }
            try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(value);
                if (!uri.IsFile || uri.IsUnc)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("value must be a local directory");
                }
                batchingDirectory = value;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid batching directory.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public MyAppKnowledgeSyncProvider()
    {
        this.proxy = new MyAppSqlSync.MyAppSqlSyncClient();
        this.proxy.Initialize();
    }

    public override void BeginSession(SyncProviderPosition position, SyncSessionContext syncSessionContext)
    {
        this.proxy.BeginSession(position);
    }

    public DbSyncScopeDescription GetScopeDescription()
    {
        return this.proxy.GetScopeDescription();
    }

    public override void EndSession(SyncSessionContext syncSessionContext)
    {
        this.proxy.EndSession();
        if (this.localBatchingDirectory != null)
        {
            this.localBatchingDirectory.Refresh();

            if (this.localBatchingDirectory.Exists)
            {
                this.localBatchingDirectory.Delete(true);
            }
        }          
    }

    public override ChangeBatch GetChangeBatch(uint batchSize, SyncKnowledge destinationKnowledge, out object changeDataRetriever)
    {
        MyAppSqlSync.GetChangesParameters changesWrapper = proxy.GetChanges(batchSize, destinationKnowledge);
        changeDataRetriever = changesWrapper.DataRetriever;

        DbSyncContext context = changeDataRetriever as DbSyncContext;
        if (context != null && context.IsDataBatched)
        {
            if (this.localBatchingDirectory == null)
            {
                string remotePeerId = context.MadeWithKnowledge.ReplicaId.ToString();
                string sessionDir = Path.Combine(this.batchingDirectory, "MyAppSync_" + remotePeerId);
                this.localBatchingDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(sessionDir);
                if (!this.localBatchingDirectory.Exists)
                {
                    this.localBatchingDirectory.Create();
                }
            }

            string localFileName = Path.Combine(this.localBatchingDirectory.FullName, context.BatchFileName);
            FileInfo localFileInfo = new FileInfo(localFileName);

            if (!localFileInfo.Exists)
            {
                byte[] remoteFileContents = this.proxy.DownloadBatchFile(context.BatchFileName);
                using (FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    localFileStream.Write(remoteFileContents, 0, remoteFileContents.Length);
                }
            }
            context.BatchFileName = localFileName;
        }
        return changesWrapper.ChangeBatch;
    }

    public override FullEnumerationChangeBatch GetFullEnumerationChangeBatch(uint batchSize, SyncId lowerEnumerationBound, SyncKnowledge knowledgeForDataRetrieval, out object changeDataRetriever)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void GetSyncBatchParameters(out uint batchSize, out SyncKnowledge knowledge)
    {
        MyAppSqlSync.SyncBatchParameters wrapper = proxy.GetKnowledge();
        batchSize = wrapper.BatchSize;
        knowledge = wrapper.DestinationKnowledge;
    }

    public override SyncIdFormatGroup IdFormats
    {
        get
        {
            if (idFormatGroup == null)
            {
                idFormatGroup = new SyncIdFormatGroup();

                idFormatGroup.ChangeUnitIdFormat.IsVariableLength = false;
                idFormatGroup.ChangeUnitIdFormat.Length = 1;

                idFormatGroup.ReplicaIdFormat.IsVariableLength = false;
                idFormatGroup.ReplicaIdFormat.Length = 16;

                idFormatGroup.ItemIdFormat.IsVariableLength = true;
                idFormatGroup.ItemIdFormat.Length = 10 * 1024;
            }
            return idFormatGroup;
        }
    }

    public override void ProcessChangeBatch(ConflictResolutionPolicy resolutionPolicy, ChangeBatch sourceChanges, object changeDataRetriever, SyncCallbacks syncCallbacks, SyncSessionStatistics sessionStatistics)
    {
        DbSyncContext context = changeDataRetriever as DbSyncContext;
        if (context != null && context.IsDataBatched)
        {
            string fileName = new FileInfo(context.BatchFileName).Name;
            string peerId = context.MadeWithKnowledge.ReplicaId.ToString();
            if (!this.proxy.HasUploadedBatchFile(fileName, peerId))
            {
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(context.BatchFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] contents = new byte[stream.Length];
                using (stream)
                {
                    stream.Read(contents, 0, contents.Length);
                }
                this.proxy.UploadBatchFile(fileName, contents, peerId);
            }

            context.BatchFileName = fileName;
        }
        SyncSessionStatistics stats = this.proxy.ApplyChanges(resolutionPolicy, sourceChanges, changeDataRetriever);
        sessionStatistics.ChangesApplied += stats.ChangesApplied;
        sessionStatistics.ChangesFailed += stats.ChangesFailed;
    }

    public override void ProcessFullEnumerationChangeBatch(ConflictResolutionPolicy resolutionPolicy, FullEnumerationChangeBatch sourceChanges, object changeDataRetriever, SyncCallbacks syncCallbacks, SyncSessionStatistics sessionStatistics)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    ~MyAppKnowledgeSyncProvider()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (this.proxy != null)
                {
                    CloseProxy();
                }
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public virtual void CloseProxy()
    {
        if (this.proxy != null)
        {
            this.proxy.Cleanup();
            ICommunicationObject channel = proxy as ICommunicationObject;
            if (channel != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    channel.Close();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    channel.Abort();
                }
                catch (CommunicationException)
                {
                    channel.Abort();
                }
            }
            this.proxy = null;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Show the code also have you looked at the .cs files based on the StackTrace you should step thru your code  Line number '3' and line position '9'. Source=PresentationFramework LineNumber=3 LinePosition=9 StackTrace: at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri) InnerException: System.SystemException Message=System error. Source=Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you for your amazingly quick response! The bit about Line number '3', position '9', was just the error message bubbling up to the first lines of the WPF Window control. If I wrap my call to orchestrator.Synchronize() in a try/catch block, I just get the inner exception part about the system error. I will try to correct my post and only include that (I'll also include some of the code).

Comment: OK...I eliminated some of the extraneous error info. As far as code, it is hard to tell what to include because all my code seems to run without error. The error is coming from the Microsoft Sync functionality. I am sure that I am CAUSING the error by the way I have structured my code, but it is hard to know how. Basically my implementation of the KnowledgeSyncProvider class acts as a wrapper to the webservice I have written. It creates a proxy (MySyncService.IMySqlSync) and calls the proxy's functionality (Proxy.BeginSession, Proxy.Initialize, and handles batching) like the example link

Comment: Syncing works, and batching seems to work but, I get the error right at the end of the process.

Comment: You need to paste the code at the end of the process we don't know what the end of your process looks like

Comment: Code is added now. Thanks very much for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, it has just started working.

I got a notification within Visual Studio 2010 that I should "update components" or "install components". It installed some web components.

Now, my code runs without error.

While I am very glad to be past this error, I am getting past it in a very unsatisfying way.

Well. I'll take what I can get.